# Is it possible to first read and then write into same spreadsheet file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I.e. I am reading `Cell(0)` and `Row(0)` value and then I write new text on the same place in the same file.

Is it possible to do same?

Answer (score 7):

This is how you do it with apache-poi. The code works for both **xls** and **xlsx** workbooks.

```
//Load the workbook into the memory
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filename_of_your_workbook");
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

//Modify the workbook as you wish
//As an example, we override the first cell of the first row in the first sheet (0-based indices)
workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue("new value for A1");


//you have to close the input stream FIRST before writing to the same file.
fis.close() ;

//save your changes to the same file.
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("filename_of_your_workbook")); 
workbook.close();
```

Note that when you create a workbook object from an existing document with apache-poi, it will load the document model into the memory and all changes will be temporary unless you persist it back to the filesystem. If you provide the same filename while calling `workbook.write()`, you are basically saving your changes to the same file.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using some additional library for reading and writing in to spreadsheet. If that is the case you just need to re-point to the same location again for writing any value.

Look at http://howtodoinjava.com/apache-commons/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/ for more information. Also if it is possible provide your code so that we can understand it better and provide good solution.

Answer (score -2):

As per my knowledge you can not open excel in append mode so you need to create a new excel using java libraries like Apache POI.

Comment: Before down voting please let us know what is wrong with post. May be we can edit and suggest a better way .